# Loading Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is populated from the code behind, and has about 300 rows. When I try to access the page containing it, everything loads, and then about 5 seconds later, the program quits and this error message appears:
[image]
If I press continue, the application stops running. However, when I look at the page, all of the data has loaded into the gridview (but of course my links, etc, don't work because the session has stopped running).

If I put less data in the table that populates the gridview, I do not get an error (it works with about 30 rows--I'm not sure the exact point where it becomes too much data). Anyway, since it is the exact same code but just less data, I know that I don't actually have an infinite loop or infinite recursion like the message suggests.

Here is the html for the gridview:

```
<div id="dvGrid" class="gridTable">
  <asp:GridView runat="server"  ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Edit" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="Edit" /> 
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Here is where it is populated in the code behind (this is in the Page_Load method):

```
DataTable dt = OpenWeather10Day.DBQueries.GetHistoricalData(_Zip);
dt.Columns["Date"].SetOrdinal(0);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
_LinkColIndex = dt.Columns["Edit"].Ordinal;
_CommentsColIndex = dt.Columns["Comments"].Ordinal;
GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

And here is the OnRowDataBound function:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {//remove double edit column and add a div in comments column to make it the correct size
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
        e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
        e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(_LinkColIndex);
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell); 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            TableCell commentsCell = e.Row.Cells[_CommentsColIndex];
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "innerDiv");
            div.InnerHtml = commentsCell.Text;
            commentsCell.Text = string.Empty;
            commentsCell.Controls.Add(div);
        }
    }
```

I have discovered that the error is with my "edit" column. If I delete the edit column from the table and get rid of all of the code related to it, all 300 rows load with no problem and the page is still active. The problem is that the edit column is critical to my page, so that is not a possible solution.

I've looked into pagination on scroll, but I can't find an example/demo that does exactly what I need or is simple enough for me to follow (I'm pretty much a complete beginner). I also don't think that it should be necessary to implement pagination; it's okay if the page takes a few seconds to load. My real problem/question is with the stack overflow that causes the session to quit. I have no idea what it is about the edit column that is causing this to occur, but somehow I need to fix this so that accessing this page doesn't quit the entire session. I am willing to add pagination on scroll if it is the only option, but like I said, I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I'm also not sure that it would fix the problem. I'm happy to post any other code, etc, if it'd be at all helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what is in your **Edit** column? Is it a Url, preformatted HTML? What will it do?

You are seeing 2 Edit columns because you have one added in your `GridView`, then you are adding a second one when you bind your data. Use the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to prevent this, then add in your other columns.

Example

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="innerDiv">
                    <%# Eval("Comments") %>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can use a `TemplateField` to put in the HTML in to your Comments column and get rid of

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

Comment: I need my columns to be auto generated because, depending on the size of the screen, different columns will be displayed (I have 5-10 columns in the table). I also need the double edit column because the edit column of the DataTable contains the HTML for a url, like this: <a href='ForecastComments.aspx?zip=49905&date=1day'>Edit, so if I leave it autogenerated, the literal text appears, when instead I want it to be a link. So, I'm creating the link column in the page with the data from the table, and then deleting the column from the table later. It's the only solution I could find.